# Standard primitive types vs custom structs in public API

Tags: c#, comparative-review, api, library

I am writing a .NET library and have a lot of properties like this:

```
public ??? SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

where valid values are 0-15 (or from 00000000 to 00001111 in binary). So I should choose a proper type of the property. I see two options:

**byte**

I can use `byte` and insert value validation in each property setter:

```
public byte SomeProperty
{
    get { return _someValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 15)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, "Message.");

        _someValue = value;
    }
}
```

Advantages:

- you don't need to cast literals from 0 to 15 to some another type.

Disadvantages:

- value check must be inserted in each property setter;
- property signature doesn't reflect valid values.

**custom value type**

Or I can create a struct like `FourBitNumber` handling invalid values in its constructor:

```
public struct FourBitNumber
{
    private readonly byte _someValue;

    public FourBitNumber(byte value)
    {
        if (value > 15)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, "Message.");

        _someValue = value;
    }
}
```

and use this struct as type for the property:

```
public FourBitNumber SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Advantages:

- user of the API takes care about passed values by casting them to `FourBitNumber` so the library always gets valid values;
- property type clearly says what valid values are.

Disadvantages:

- you need always cast values of primitive types to `FourBitNumber` which is inconvenient especially with literals.

---

At now the second way seems better for me but necessity of casting everywhere is really annoying. What other aspects should I take into an account to take final decision?

Comment: Perhaps copy what .NET does for Int16 or Int32 stucts, which declare many IConvertible calls:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252

Answer (score 1):

## custom value type

I would use this becasue the disadvantage that you name

> you need always cast values of primitive types to FourBitNumber which is inconvenient especially with literals.

can be easily overcome by implementing an [`implict operator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) for `FourBitNumber` to `byte`:

```
public static implicit operator byte(FourBitNumber value) => value._someValue;
```

and an explicit one for `byte` to `FourBitNumber`

```
public static explicit operator FourBitNumber(byte value) => new FourBitNumber(value);
```

so now it doesn't have any disadvanteges ;-)

Comment: You can't do casting from `byte` to `FourBitNumber` implicit because operators that can fail should be explicit... :)

Comment: @Maxim I've never heard of that. You should cast explicitly if there is a risk of loosing data and not becasue an exception can occur.

Comment: From MSDN: "In general, implicit conversion operators **should never throw exceptions** and never lose information". Loosing of data is one of criteria, the second one is throwing exceptions. So `operator FourBitNumber(byte value)` should be explicit.

Comment: @Maxim well, actually it makes sense becasue when converting `byte` to `FourBitNumber` you can loose information so it should be explicit but the other way around would work. After all I was right (and corrected my asnwer) ;-]

Comment: When I tried approach with `FourBitNumber` I of course created these operators. But `explicit` means I need always cast values, so I still have the disadavantage :( With this code `SomeProperty = (FourBitNumber)5` it is especially inconvenient since 5 obviously falls in valid range...

Comment: @Maxim I don't think there are any other options. Maybe if you posted more code and some real use cases then other suggestions would be possible but with this example I don't think so.

Comment: Anyway thank you. I'm just trying to figure out if it will be comfortable to work with an API that uses validation implemented in this way.

Comment: @Maxim I guess the compilers of the future will be able to support our custom types. This would be a really cool feature :-] who knows... perhaps they are already working on it...